# Convert MSISDN number into bytes

Tags: c#, .net, packet, pcap

I try to build `GTP packet` and i have example `PCAP` files.
my `MSIDSN` number in my exapmle is `8615221000101` and become into 7 bytes: `68 51 22 01 00 01 f1` and i wonder how this calculated and become this value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look your number is `8615221000101` Now divide into 7 parts `86` `15` `22` `10` `00` `1`. Now reverse the digits of each part and you get `68` `51` `22` `01` `00` `1` thats exactly what you got as a result.

Seems as if the MSISDN number is a set of bytes in a different order. The `f1` comes because the following space after `1` was filled with four 1-bits.